# Vimeo - Like Button Not Showing With Embedded Videos

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm trying to embed some videos on one of my websites and I'm also trying to include the like button and pull the number of likes via the new API. Even though the "Show Like Button" is checked in the settings for the videos, it is not showing up on any of the videos that I have embedded. I've looked around to try and troubleshoot and, yes, I am completely logged out of Vimeo. I have tried it in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Maxthon. I've cleared the cache and cookies and even tried it with the incognito mode with chrome and the private mode with Maxthon. All with no luck. What's going on here?

Here's the link to the forum post that I created on Vimeo.com

https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:115629

Answer (score 1):

Encountered similar issue: share button doesn't appear on mobile if video has a privacy setting like "only people with the link".

Set the video to "Public", and the share buttons etc. will show.

Answer (score 0):

So after speaking with the `Vimeo` staff over at https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:115629 , it would seem as though placing a video in "private" mode means that the "Like" button will not show up, but the "Share" and "Watch Later" buttons will still show up if chosen. Not really sure why you can't "Like" a private/hidden video, but yet you can "Share" and "Watch Later". Doesn't make any sense, but that's just the way it is for the moment.